# Flux OCI with kubernetes on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, gitops, fluxcd

I have switched from using tradition way of pushing helm chart to oci format.

But on then kubernetes cluster the charts are not getting installed and I am getting the below error:

```
chart pull error: chart pull error: failed to download chart for remote reference: temp.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo/abc:1.0.1: not found
chart pull error: chart pull error: failed to download chart for remote reference:
```

My new repository is :

```
oci://abc.azurecr.io/charts
```

instead of

```
https://abc.azurecr.io/helm/v1
```

Also In kubernetes cluster the helm path is not getting updated to charts, I am not sure why it is still poiting to

```
/helm/v1 path
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below output***

*I have enabled the OCI experimental support for helm versions*

```
export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
helm version
```

***I have created the container registry***

[image]

*I have created the sample chat and saved the chart into the local archive*

```
cd .. 
helm package .
```

*I have given the some registry credentials and also created the service principal using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal)*

***I have logged into the registry using below command***

```
helm registry login Registry_name.azurecr.io
```

*we have to give the username and password of the registry*

[image]

***I run the helm push command to push the chart to registry as a OCI format***

```
helm push hello-world-0.1.0.tgz oci://registry_name.azurecr.io/helm
```

[image]

***I have used the below command to show the properties of the repository***

```
az acr repository show \
  --name repository_name \
  --repository helm/hello-world
```

[image]

***To check the data stored in the repository***

```
az acr manifest list-metadata \
  --registry myregistry890 \
  --name helm/hello-world
```

***I have pulled the chat using below command***

```
helm pull oci://repository_name.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world --version 0.1.0
```

[image]